# How to build a numbered list parser in nom?

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I'd like to parse a numbered list using `nom` in Rust.

For example, `1. Milk 2. Bread 3. Bacon`.

I could use `separated_list1` with an appropriate separator parser and element parser.

```rs
fn parser(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<&str>> {
    preceded(
        tag("1. "),
        separated_list1(
            tuple((tag(" "), digit1, tag(". "))),
            take_while(is_alphabetic),
        ),
    )(input)
}
```

However, this does not validate the increasing index numbers.

For example, it would happily parse invalid lists like `1. Milk 3. Bread 4. Bacon` or `1. Milk 8. Bread 1. Bacon`.

It seems there is no built-in nom parser that can do this. So I ventured to try to build my own first parser...

My idea was to implement a parser similar to `separated_list1` but which keeps track of the index and passes it to the separator as argument. It could accept a closure as argument that can then create the separator parser based on the index argument.

```rs
fn parser(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<&str>> {
    preceded(
        tag("1. "),
        separated_list1(
            |index: i32| tuple((tag(" "), tag(&index.to_string()), tag(". "))),
            take_while(is_alphabetic),
        ),
    )(input)
}
```

I tried to use the implementation of `separated_list1` and change the separator argument to `G: FnOnce(i32) -> Parser<I, O2, E>,`, create an index variable `let mut index = 1;`, pass it to `sep(index)` in the loop, and increase it at the end of the loop `index += 1;`.

However, Rust's type system is not happy!

How can I make this work?

---

Here's the full code for reproduction

```rs
use nom::{
    error::{ErrorKind, ParseError},
    Err, IResult, InputLength, Parser,
};

pub fn separated_numbered_list1<I, O, O2, E, F, G>(
    mut sep: G,
    mut f: F,
) -> impl FnMut(I) -> IResult<I, Vec<O>, E>
where
    I: Clone + InputLength,
    F: Parser<I, O, E>,
    G: FnOnce(i32) -> Parser<I, O2, E>,
    E: ParseError<I>,
{
    move |mut i: I| {
        let mut res = Vec::new();
        let mut index = 1;

        // Parse the first element
        match f.parse(i.clone()) {
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
            Ok((i1, o)) => {
                res.push(o);
                i = i1;
            }
        }

        loop {
            let len = i.input_len();
            match sep(index).parse(i.clone()) {
                Err(Err::Error(_)) => return Ok((i, res)),
                Err(e) => return Err(e),
                Ok((i1, _)) => {
                    // infinite loop check: the parser must always consume
                    if i1.input_len() == len {
                        return Err(Err::Error(E::from_error_kind(i1, ErrorKind::SeparatedList)));
                    }

                    match f.parse(i1.clone()) {
                        Err(Err::Error(_)) => return Ok((i, res)),
                        Err(e) => return Err(e),
                        Ok((i2, o)) => {
                            res.push(o);
                            i = i2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            index += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does valid input always start with a known index? Like 0 or 1 perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the list index always starts at 1. and counts up in integer increments.

Comment: Then store your values in a vec as you parse them and compare the size of the vec to your key, the index is the key for that value

Comment: You may have to use `many1()` and `separated_pair()` manually, though

Comment: Oh right, I'm mixing lexing and parsing. Probably should do the validation later in a separate step.

Comment: I think I have what you want. Needed a compiler to check, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually use [many1()](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/multi/fn.many1.html), [separated_pair()](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/sequence/fn.separated_pair.html), and [verify()](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/combinator/fn.verify.html)

```
fn validated(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Vec<(u32, &str)>> {
    let current_index = Cell::new(1u32);
    let number = map_res(digit1, |s: &str| s.parse::<u32>());
    let valid = verify(number, |digit| {
        let i = current_index.get();
        if digit == &i {
            current_index.set(i + 1);
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    });
    let pair = preceded(multispace0, separated_pair(valid, tag(". "), alpha1));
    //give current_index time to be used and dropped with a temporary binding. This will not compile without the temporary binding 
    let tmp = many1(pair)(input);
    tmp
}

#[test]
fn test_success() {
    let input = "1. Milk 2. Bread 3. Bacon";
    assert_eq!(validated(input), Ok(("", vec![(1, "Milk"), (2, "Bread"), (3, "Bacon")])));
}

#[test]
fn test_fail() {
    let input = "2. Bread 3. Bacon 1. Milk";
    validated(input).unwrap_err();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is clever. It feels like using `Cell` for global state and a temporary binding to make it all work is fighting Rust a bit though. With your previous suggestion I was able to implement a simple `map_res`, checking if the numbers in the vec are all properly increasing, e.g. `vec.iter().enumerate().all(|(i, val)| val.1 == i + 1)`, and returning a custom error if not, e.g. `Err(nom::Err::Error(MyError::IncreasingNumberedList))`. Not as good as yours though which immediately errors upon an invalid index.

Comment: We're more fighting the signature of `verify()` here, since it accepts a `Fn` and not `FnMut` meaning we can't mutable close over any out of scope values. Also, the compiler *may* elide the cell completely in release mode. I admit to the inelegance of reading this solution, though.